# Parse HTML element after element with given contents

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the contents from an HTML element which follows an element having specific content "ID".

For example, in content of the data-tip attribute  below, I would like to extract the content 1886G from the  element following a  ID  tag in all cases.

I am using beautifulsoup4 in python to do the parsing, once to identify content based on the id, and another to parse the data-tip content string back to html.  I have attempted to grab the ID using a findNextSibling() like so:

```
import os
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_file = BeautifulSoup(open("data_sample.html"), "html.parser")

for tag in html_file.findAll(id = re.compile("^content.*")):
    dataTip = BeautifulSoup(tag["data-tip"], "html.parser")
    print("find ID:")
    print(dataTip.findNextSibling("tr", attrs = {"th" : "ID"}))
```

The output is

```
find ID:
None
```

Here is one example element:

```
<div id="content_placement_o_89879879789" style="z-index: 77; position: absolute; width: 25px; height: 43px; left: 124.0px; top: 344.0px;" data-tip="<table width='200'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<td>Generic Phone Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<td>1886G</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Status</th>
<td>Same</td>
</tr>
</table>
">
<img alt="Image" class="same_mark_10987024  same_mark_highlighted" height="43" id="s_o_848483938748" src="https://website/picture.gif" style="position: absolute" width="25">
</div>
```

Clearly I am missing something about how this function works.  Does anyone know what I can change to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `findNextSibling` on the `th` tag whose text is `ID` instead of `tr` which has a parent child relationship with the tag you are trying to find, or to be more explicit, `th` and `td` are children of `tr` while `th` and `td` are siblings to each other:

```
import re
for tag in html_file.findAll(id = re.compile("^content.*")):
    dataTip = BeautifulSoup(tag["data-tip"], "html.parser")
    id = dataTip.find("th", text = "ID").findNextSibling().text
    print(id)

# 1886G
```

Comment: I see now, this is exactly what I was looking for.